# Get User's location from ubuntu of Microsoft Exchange server

Tags: ubuntu, outlook, location, exchange-server, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to get any user's location information from ubuntu platform.
Have searched and found few references but couldn't proceed further.

below are the links of references i found:

1) [FindPeople operation of Exchange server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_0)

2) [Work city](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191348(v=exchg.150).aspx)

3) [ExchangeImpersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565690(v=exchg.150).aspx)

There are few python clients to connect to Exchange server as well:

1) [Exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib)

2) [pyexchange](https://github.com/linkedin/pyexchange)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location (if this is the location in the AD and therefore in the Exchange Object and not the real location from a user based on his IP address fetched from Exchange logfiles) is part from the Active Directory attribute.

So an easy option to get this kind of AD properties would be to create a taskuser and then use LDAP (provided by your Domain controller) to check the information. Then no EWS would be needed and you are open to pick any developer language you require to perform such a LDAP search.

However if you do not have access to the Domain Controller (due to the reason that the Ubuntu OS/PC is outside of the local LAN) then [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx) (as you already pointed out) might be your only option here.